# What is the difference between Broken Access Control and Insecure Direct Object reference?

Tags: access-control, authorization, owasp

If I understand correctly, the main difference is that the user must be logged in to carry out an insecure direct object reference attack but he doesn't have to be logged in to exploit a broken access control attack.

Do I have this right? What are the differences?

Answer (score 5):

Definition of Insecure Direct Object Reference from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Insecure_Direct_Object_References_%28OWASP-AZ-004%29):

> Insecure Direct Object References occur when an application provides direct access to objects based on user-supplied input. As a result of this vulnerability attackers can bypass authorization and access resources in the system directly, for example database records or files.

Definition of  Broken Access Control from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Broken_Access_Control)

> Access control, sometimes called authorization, is how a web
>   application grants access to content and functions to some users and
>   not others. These checks are performed after authentication, and
>   govern what ‘authorized’ users are allowed to do. Access control
>   sounds like a simple problem but is insidiously difficult to implement
>   correctly. A web application’s access control model is closely tied to
>   the content and functions that the site provides. In addition, the
>   users may fall into a number of groups or roles with different
>   abilities or privileges.

Depending on how you want to interpret these non-standard terms, they could be construied as the same.

However, direct object access typically means there is a lack of an authentication control in order to gain access to privileged information whereas broken access control indicates the access control is not functioning as intended.

For example, if you create reports for a specific user at some URL like: `http://example.com/some-report/report-1231231231312.pdf` and the application does not require authentication this would be direct object access. It is possible the developers never implemented any access control in the first place, therefore, the access control is not broken, it just direct object access - i.e., the report is written to a url, but it's just a file location separate from the core application so the application does not have control over delivery of the resource.

In many cases, both terms could be used to describe the same vulnerability as well. E.g., The report is generated dynamically only for logged in users, but the report is accessible later without having to log in. In this case, developers only put the access control on the function to create the report but not to access.

Insecure direct object reference

Comment: I think both of them is same. Because official OWASP pdf document treats both concepts in the same way: https://owasp.org/www-chapter-ghana/assets/slides/IDOR.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific instance of each vulnerability.  Insecure Direct Object Reference is generally where a database object has an ID exposed to the client.  So for example in an app using REST style URLs we could have

```
http://myapp.test/users/2
```

showing your user account and then if you change to

```
http://myapp.test/users/4
```

it shows you someone elses account.  In this instance you would need to be logged in, but AFAIK there's nothing in the vulnerability specification that says that you accessing for example

```
http://myapp.test/page/12
```

whilst unauthenticated wouldn't be insecure DOR assuming that the page is only meant to be accessed while logged in.

Broken access control is a more general case where a control over access to application functionality isn't correctly controlled, but without the requirement for it to relate to accessing a database object.

So for example.

```
http://myapp.test/super_secret_admin_panel
```

being accessible without authentication would be a broken access control.  but you could have a situation where it relates to authenticated users getting access to functionality they shouldn't, so an ordinary staff member accessing

```
http://myapp.test/all_staff_salary_details
```

when this should only be accessible by members of the HR department.

**So the TL;DR is no both those issues can occur regardless of whether the user is logged in.**

Comment: the `user 2` vs `user 4` thing may also potentially be classified as horizontal privilege escalation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation#Horizontal_privilege_escalation